# How Macro Will show me the sheet's name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with three sheets: Peter, Jone and Paul. these are the names of 3 sheets.
Now i have set up a macro which will ask their name and if they click on YES they can visualize or write the specific page only. For Instance Peter can not see Jone's workbook. when Jones is opening the file excel is asking the questions randomly like "Are you Peter?"
and if he clicks on yes then Excel will ask for the password as the sheet is protected. In may case all the sheets are opened and protected.

I want to make it more solid..........When I will open the excel file it will show me the macro in which I want to go? Macro will ask me the question in which sheet I want to go and the same sheet will open up?

Can anyone help me?